# JavaFX (with FXML) Adding Action events for buttons

Tags: javafx

I have a FXML-File build with Scene-Builder with the needed fx:ids and the following controller:

```
public class LaunchLogin extends Application{

public static void main (String [] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //ResourceLoader rl = ResourceLoader.getInstance();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/gfx/gui/LoginScreenUI.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/gfx/gui/cogfitStyle.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle ("CogFit");
    primaryStage.show();
}
@FXML
Button btn_newUser;


@FXML
Button btn_changePW;

@FXML
Button btn_send;

@FXML
private void test(ActionEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("success");
}
}
```

Now I want to add action events to the buttons. How do I do that? I cannot really find something that involves FXML-Files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for adding event handlers via FXML is described by [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#event_handler_attributes). It uses the `#` symbol along with the appropriate `onXXX` attribute. For example, if you have the following controller:

```
package example;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;  
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private void printHelloWorld(ActionEvent event) {
        event.consume();
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }

}
```

Then the FXML file might look something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
           fx:controller="example.Controller" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="300">

    <Button text="Click me!" onAction="#printHelloWorld"/>

</StackPane>
```

You can configure this using Scene Builder by clicking on the desired node and going to the "Code" panel on the right side. There will be fields for the various `onXXX` properties as well as a field for `fx:id`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Scene Builder under "Code" there is a field onAction. You have to put the name of the method in your controller class there. Or add the following code to the button properties in the FXML file:

```
onAction="#method"
```